# Beamer metropolis math font

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex, beamer-metropolis

I'm trying to change the math font in a beamer (with metropolis user theme) document.
I'm using XeLatex. I've managed to change the text font using `fontenc` but this style does not apply to math equation. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}


  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}


\title{\textbf{Title}}
\date{24 Giugno 2018}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Indice}
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
  \tableofcontents%[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section[Introduction]{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Concetti generali della rinormalizzazione (I)}
Equation number 1
\begin{equation}
    F(x) = g_0 + g_0^2F_1(x) + g_0^3F_2(x) + \dots .
\end{equation}
Second equation for F1
\begin{equation}
    F_1(x) = \alpha \int_0^\infty dt \frac{1}{x+t},
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to change the math font to the default LaTeX font.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use computer modern font with the `metropolis` theme is to simply not compile with xelatex/lualatex. If you compile with pdflatex, the theme will automatically use the default computer modern font. You could also switch to the `moloch` theme, a more modern fork of the `metropolis` theme, which does not mess with the fonts.

If you then want to switch from sans serif to serif, you can do this by loading the `serif` font theme:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{serif}
%    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}


  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}


\title{\textbf{Title}}
\date{24 Giugno 2018}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Concetti generali della rinormalizzazione (I)}
Equation number 1
\begin{equation}
    F(x) = g_0 + g_0^2F_1(x) + g_0^3F_2(x) + \dots .
\end{equation}
Second equation for F1
\begin{equation}
    F_1(x) = \alpha \int_0^\infty dt \frac{1}{x+t},
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on using xelatex, you could use the `unicode-math` theme to change the math font. In the following example, I'm using `Libertinus Math`. Change this to whatever math font would like to use. Please note that you should not use the `fontenc` package with xelatex. You probably meant to use the `fontspec` package, which is automatically loaded by the metropolis theme if you compile with xelatex.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setsansfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}


  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}


\title{\textbf{Title}}
\date{24 Giugno 2018}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{Concetti generali della rinormalizzazione (I)}
Equation number 1
\begin{equation}
    F(x) = g_0 + g_0^2F_1(x) + g_0^3F_2(x) + \dots .
\end{equation}
Second equation for F1
\begin{equation}
    F_1(x) = \alpha \int_0^\infty dt \frac{1}{x+t},
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just load `unicode-math` and set the font theme to `serif`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

% you don't want to have long paragraphs
% so why justify?
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}


\title{\textbf{Title}}
\date{24 Giugno 2018}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Indice}
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
  \tableofcontents%[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section[Introduction]{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Concetti generali della rinormalizzazione (I)}
Equation number 1 with \themename and CMU Serif
\begin{equation}
    F(x) = g_0 + g_0^2F_1(x) + g_0^3F_2(x) + \dots .
\end{equation}
Second equation for F1
\begin{equation}
    F_1(x) = \alpha \int_0^\infty dt \, \frac{1}{x+t},
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]